# KafkaStreams app has java threads overhead

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Having KafkaStreams topology which consumes and after some processing steps produces results to another kafka topic and configured with:

```
num.stream.threads: 10
```

JConsole says there are 20 consumer threads, 20 producer threads, 20 hearthbeat threads.

Why do number of such threads is 20 instead of 10? it seems like a significant overhead in case of large number of num.stream.threads - in production we have configured 64 and in there are more than 400 Java native threads.

Comment: Are you running 2 instances of your application?

Comment: no, single instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason why there are double number of threads. We used spring-kafka StreamsBuilderFactoryBean to create KafkaStream which creates KafkaStream under the hood. After removing it number of threads has been divided by 2.

Answer (score 0):

Each `StreamThread` (as configured via `num.stream.threads`), creates a consumer, restore consumer, (maybe global consumer), and one producer (if "exactly-once processin" is disabled; of you enable exactly-once processing, even more producers are created).

Each consumer client starts a heartbeat background thread. Each Producer client start a background sender thread. That's is why you see more threads.